# Converse of Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, chinese-remainder-theorem

**Chinese Remainder Theorem for commutative rings with identity**

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. If $I, J$ are ideals of $R$ satisfying $I+J=R$, then there is an isomorphism of rings:
$$R/(I\cap J) \cong R/I \times R/J.$$

I am interested in the converse of this. I saw the following two cases:

**Converse V1**

If we have positive integers $m, n$ with $(m,n)\neq 1$, then 
$$
\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z} \not\cong \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}.$$

This one is easy if we consider characteristics.

**Converse V2**

Let $F$ be a field. If we have polynomials $f, g \in F[x]$ with $(f)+(g)\neq F[x]$, then 
$$
F[x]/(f(x)g(x))\not\cong F[x]/(f(x))\times F[x]/(g(x)).$$

This one is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456795/if-gcdfx-gx-ne1-then-fx-fg-is-not-isomorphic-to-fx-f-times/456834#456834). The idea is counting number of ideals of both sides. It is easy to see that if we have factorization of ideals into prime ideals (Dedekind Domain), the same idea applies.

However, we have this example:

**Example**
If $R=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}$ and $I=J=(0)$, then $I+J\neq R$ and
$$
R/(I\cap J) \cong \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z} \cong \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}\times \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z} \cong R/I\times R/J.$$

Thus, the converse of CRT does not hold in general for "commutative ring with identity". We have seen, however, the converse of CRT holds for "Dedekind Domain". My question is

**Quetion**
Do we have a commutative ring with identity which is not a "Dedekind Domain" such that the converse of CRT holds?

Comment: How does the counterexample fit with [this theorem](https://i.imgur.com/xJElgzC.png)?

Comment: The theorem is for the natural injective homomorphism, but I am asking for just isomorphism.

Comment: If you are still interested in this question , then I might mention that If $I,J$ are ideals of a commutative ring $R$ with unity and $f : R/{I \cap J} \to R/I \times R/J$ is the natural injective ring homomorphism given by $f(x + I \cap J)=(x+I ,x+J) , \forall x \in R$ , then $f$ is surjective if and only if $I+J=R$ . This is Proposition 1.10 of Chapter 1 of Atiyah , Macdonald's Commutative Algebra book . It is easy to prove , you should also try it yourself

Comment: It is the converse of CRT, meaning that the injective homomorphism is not necessarily assumed to be the natural one.

Comment: yeah I understand that ... it's a good question