# Multi-pullbacks and the relative chinese remainder theorem

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory, ideals, chinese-remainder-theorem

Let $I,J$ be two-sided ideals of a ring $R$. In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553430/relative-chinese-remainder-theorem-and-the-lattice-of-ideals) I asked for an "automatic" proof of the fact the natural map $R/(I\cap J)\rightarrow R/I\times _{R/(I+J)} R/J$ is an isomorphism. At any rate, if $I,J$ are comaximal, this immediately yields an isomorphism $R/(I\cap J)\cong R/I\times R/J$.

Now for $n$ ideals. I'll denote the multi-pullback of the arrows $R/I_k\rightarrow R/(\require{amsart}\Large +$$_k I_k)$ by $P$. There is clearly a canonical map $R/\bigcap_ kI_k\rightarrow P$ and <s>by an analogous direct proof it is an iso</s> *(Incorrect; see answer)*. Now, if I try to collapse into the chinese remainder theorem, I find myself merely asking for $I_k$ to *jointly* cover $R$, i.e $\require{amsart}\Large +$$_k I_k=R$. On the other hand, every source I've seen asks for $I_k$ to be *pairwise* comaximal.

Why is this?

**Added:** As mentioned in the comments, the result just ain't true without pairwise comaximality, so I'm missing something in the diagrams. Each of the squares below is both a pullback and a pushout.
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
    R/(I_i\cap I_j) @>>> R/I_i\\ @VVV @VVV\\
    R/I_j @>>> R/(I_i+I_j)
    \end{CD}$$
Hence, each square from the multi-pullback
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
    R/\bigcap_kI_k @>>> R/I_i\\ @VVV @VVV\\
    R/I_j @>>> R/\sum_kI_k
    \end{CD}$$
factors through the one above and we get induced maps $R/\bigcap_kI_k\rightarrow R/(I_i\cap I_j)$ and $R/(I_i+I_j)\rightarrow R/\sum_kI_k$. What's the missing link?

**Added again:** I'm getting increasingly large diagrams and starting to think this needs all kinds of combinatorial stuff related to covers. Hoping there's an elegant argument that cuts through this.

Comment: There are obvious examples, which show that one needs pairwise coprime ideals. For example consider $(1),(2),(2)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. Then $R/(I_1\cap I_2\cap I_3)=\mathbb{Z}/(2)$ and $R/I_1\times R/I_2\times R/I_3=\mathbb{Z}/(2)\times\mathbb{Z}/(2)$.

Comment: @Arrow Did you have any progress with this? Have you found some kind of extension of the relative CRT for $n>2$ ideals?

Comment: @JoseBrox Unfortunately I have nothing new to say or ask about this question for now :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $R/\bigcap_ kI_k\rightarrow P$ is not generally an isomorphism. This is clear if one thinks concretely. Too bad I was determined to work with diagrams alone. Comaximality is a convenient condition to make sure this map is an iso.

Already in the case of three ideals $I,J,K$, the problem is that there are no induced maps $P\rightarrow R/(I\cap J)$ because the square below need not commute.
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
    P @>>> R/I\\ @VVV @VVV\\
    R/J @>>> R/(I+J)
    \end{CD}$$
Commutativity would mean the implication below, which has no reason to hold. $$r+I+J+K=s+J+K+I\implies r+I+J=s+J+I$$ In the binary case the square is a pullback, so commutativity is not an issue.

Now for the comaximality. As [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379955/converse-of-chinese-remainder-theorem?rq=1) shows, comaximality is not a necessary condition for the binary CRT.
By associativity, $P$ can be calculated via iterated pullbacks. By induction based on the binary case, we can tentatively calculate $$\begin{aligned} P & \;\;= (R/\bigcap _{k=1}^{n-2}I_k\times _{R/\sum_{k=1}^n}R/I_{n-1}) \times_{R/\sum_{k=1}^n}R/I_n \\  & \overset{\text{I wish}}{=} (R/\bigcap _{k=1}^{n-2}I_k\times _{R/\sum_{k=1}^{\color{#c00}{n-1}}}R/I_{n-1}) \times_{R/\sum_{k=1}^n}R/I_n  
\\ & \;\;=R/\bigcap_{k=1}^{n-1}\times _{R/\sum_{k=1}^nI_k}R/I_n
\\ & \overset{\text{I wish}}{=}R/\bigcap_{k=1}^{n-1}\times _{R/(\color{#c00}{\bigcap_{k=1}^{n-1}I_k+I_n)}}R/I_n
\\ & \;\;=R/\bigcap_{k=1}^nI_k
\end{aligned}$$

Sufficient conditions would be $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n, \sum_{k=1}^nI_k=\bigcap_{k=1}^{n-1}I_k+I_n$. We want these to hold for all $1\leq k\leq n, n\geq 3$. An easy condition for the first equality is pairwise comaximality. The following fact takes care of the second one.

**Fact.** Let $I_1,\dots,I_n$ be pairwise comaximal ideals. Then $I_j,\prod_{k\neq j}I_k$ are comaximal. (Proof by induction.) In particular, $I_j,\bigcap_{k\neq j}I_k$ are comaximal since $\prod_kI_k\subset \bigcap _kI_k$.

So for pairwise comaximal ideals the tentative calculation is justified. Since we're pulling back over $R/\sum_k I_k$ and $\sum_kI_k=R$, $P$ is just the product $\prod _kR/I_k$ and we have the Chinese remainder theorem. If the ring is moreover commutative, then multiplication and intersection coincide for pairwise comaximal ideals, and we have $\prod _kR/I_k\cong R/\prod_kI_k$.